# Como puedo dividir un string en partes iguales

Tags: php, string, split

Recibo un string con n caracteres, lo que quiero es poder dividir ese string en 4 partes, no importa si no tienen la misma cantidad de caracteres, lo importante es que siempre me devuelva 4 partes.

```
<?php
$str = "hello friend";
$tam = strlen($str)/4;
print_r($tam);
$arr2 = str_split($str, $tam);
print_r($arr2);
?>
```

lo intente con ese pero solo funciona cuando es múltiplo de 4. los string pueden ser

```
array[0] = 'h';
array[1] = 'e';
array[2] = 'l';
array[3] = 'lo friend';
```

con que tenga 4 partes exactas.

Answer (score 1):

Con la siguiente función podrás dividir un string en la cantidad de pedazos que quieras, haciendo las divisiones lo **más simétricas posible**.

Para ello primero hay que calcular la longitud de cada pedazo de la cadena `$long_partes`. Como no siempre va a ser exacto, el resto se lo asigno a una variable `$sobrante`.

El ciclo `while` iterará de 0 hasta la cantidad de partes. Mientras el sobrante no sea 0, a cada pedazo se le agrega una unidad del sobrante, lo que le llamo `$offset`. 
Si se diera el caso de que la cantidad de partes superara a la longitud del string, cuando llega a la parte que se desborda, entonces entra en el `else` y se reemplaza por un caracter en blanco.

```
<?php
function div_string($str, $num_partes) {
    $slong = strlen($str);
    $long_partes = intval($slong/$num_partes);
    $sobrante = $slong % $num_partes;
    $i = 0;
    $start = 0;
    $arr2 = array();
    while($i < $num_partes) {
        if($i < $slong) {
            $offset = ($sobrante > 0) ? $long_partes+1 : $long_partes;
            $arr2[] = substr($str, $start, $offset);
            $start += $offset;
            $sobrante--;
        } else {
            // Cuando $i es mayor que la longitud de la cadena
            // O sea que la longitud total es menor que la cantidad de partes
            $arr2[] = '';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $arr2;
}
```

Ejemplos:

```
print_r(div_string("Hello friend", 4));
// array('Hel', 'lo ', 'fri', 'end')
print_r(div_string("Una cadena de prueba.", 5));
// array('Una c', 'aden', 'a de', ' pru', 'eba.')
print_r(div_string("Test", 6));
// array('T', 'e', 's', 't', '', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Se ingresara una palabra en la variable **$texto** y la cantidad de partes que se desean dividir la palabra en la variable **$partes** en este caso "esta es una palabra nueva" y 4.

El software realizara una obtención de datos, el tamaño de la palabra que sera guardado en **$tamano** el tamaño que se le sera asignado cada parte que sera guardado en **$tamano_parte**, luego se verificara si el resultado de cada parte es entero o decimal, esto es por que cuando son decimales a una parte le va a tocar menos o más caracteres. Cuando es decimal taca realizar un redondeo, esto es para que pueda ser mejor distribuido la cantidad de decimales, ya que él redondeó lo tomara como en el siguiente ejemplo:

Si se redonde 4,6 el redondeo tomara 5, pero si fuese 4,4, el redondeo tomara 4.

Entonces se procede a realizar la distribución hasta la penúltima parte, la ultima como es un caso especial se le daría lo sobrante. Mientras que si fuese entero se le daría a todos por partes iguales.

```
<?php 
$texto = "esta es una palabra nueva";//palabra que deseas dividir
$partes = 4;//partes que quieres
$tamano =  strlen($texto);//tamano total de la palabra
$tamano_parte = $tamano/$partes;//tamano de pertenencia de cada parte
if(is_float($tamano_parte)){//dos casos si el tamano de cada parte es entero o flotante
    $redondeado = round($tamano_parte);//si es flotante redondeamos el tamano de cada parte
    for ($i=0; $i < $partes; $i++) { //realizamos el for del numero de partes
        if($i==$partes-1){//este  if controla la ultima parte ya que no sera igual al resto
            $array[$i] = substr($texto, -$tamano+$i*$redondeado,$tamano-$i*$redondeado);//la ultima parte tomara todo lo que sobre
        }else{
            $array[$i] = substr($texto, -$tamano+$i*$redondeado, $redondeado);//esta parte tomara partes iguales faltando la ultima
        }
    }
}else{
    for ($i=0; $i < $partes; $i++) { //for para dividir nuestras partes
        $array[$i] = substr($texto, -$tamano+$i*$tamano_parte, $tamano_parte);// se dividira todo en partes iguales
    }
} ?>
```

para imprimir solo deberas añadir esto al final esto al final.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $partes; $i++) { 
   echo $array[$i];
}
```

Comment: El idioma oficial del sitio es el español, traduce tu respuesta y revisa [answer] para conocer como se recomienda realizar respuestas en el sitio, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, estare mas pendiente de cómo responder la siguiente vez.